# angular2(production mode)-EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection

Tags: angular

In Development mode, I didn't get any error related this but after deploying the project -EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.
an error is coming (because it is in production mode).

Please anyone can give the solution in angular 2

Comment: That's a server problem. As the error message says: your server's SSE emitter is supposed to send back a response with a content type set to text/event-stream, but it sends back a response with text/html instead. Or the client is not using the correct URL to get that even stream.

Comment: I am new to angularjs so please suggest what i have to do for that one

Comment: As for every error: read it to know what it's about, read its stack trace to know where it's being thrown, find in the code that causes the error, reproduce it, and find out what is wrong. But again, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with Angular.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i have done all you suggested but i mentioned in angular because in my sense angular means if whether any changes has to do in config or any other component file or startup file etc(because i don't know the connectivity that much and also i am getting this only when i am running in production mode)... but it's ok thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
StartUp.cs:
    Before：
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
    After：
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true
        });
```